# Laravel Passing Variable from Forms

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am brand new to Laravel, and following a super basic tutorial.
However the tutorial did not come with an edit record section, which I am attempting to extend myself.

Route:

```
Route::controller('admin/products', 'ProductsController');
```

Controller:

```
class ProductsController extends BaseController
{ 

public function getUpdate($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);

        if ($product) {
            $product->title = Input::get('title');
            $product->save();
            return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')->with('message', 'Product Updated');
        }
        return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')->with('message', 'Invalid Product');
}

..ECT...
```

I realise the controller is requesting an ID to use, but I cannot figure out how to  pass it a product ID when the form is posted/get.

Form:

```
{{Form::open(array("url"=>"admin/products/update",'method' => 'get', 'files'=>true))}}
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{ Form::label('title', 'Title:') }}
            {{ Form::text('title') }}
            {{ Form::hidden('id', $product->id) }}

 ..ECT...

{{ Form::close() }}
```

my initial idea was to pass the product id within the form URL like:

```
{{Form::open(array("url"=>"admin/products/update/{{product->id}}", 'files'=>true))}}
```

But no luck with that either.

The error I get is:

```
Missing argument 1 for ProductsController::postUpdate()
```

Interestingly if I type directly into the URL:

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/products/update/3
```

It works and the item with id 3 is altered fine.

So can anyone help and inform me how to pass the id with a form?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first Problem here ist the following:

```
{{Form::open(array("url"=>"admin/products/update/{{product->id}}", 'files'=>true))}}
```

the `{{product->id}}` is wrong in two ways:

1. it should be `{{$product->id}}`
2. BUT it wouldn't work anyway because the inner {{..}} inside of the {{Form::...}} won't be recognized since it is inside a string and therefore part of the string itself.

You either have to write it this way:

```
{{Form::open(array("url"=>"admin/products/update/".$product->id, 'files'=>true))}}
```

or you give your route a name in your `routes.php` file and do it this way:

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => array('route.name', $product->id, 'files'=>true)))}}
```

I prefer the second way.

You also might want to look into [Form Model Bingin](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your speedy reply, and step by step simple suggestions.

I chose to try the first option, I have never covered named routes yet, and I get this result:
Controller method not found.

I will mark as correct if I am still missing something obvious? Thanks

Comment: That error just means that you try to access a method the controller does not have OR that you have a controller that is namespaced BUT you don't access that controller with its FULL name

Comment: Oh never mind, I added Method =>''get" to the form (as my method is getUpdate and not default post) and all went well.

I will read up on the binding, good call.

Thanks very much!